# Saving Tensorflow Graph and Variables while excluding Adam Optimizer Variables

Tags: tensorflow, model, save, adam

I am saving a tensor flow graph and variables using :

```
 builder = tf.saved_model.builder.SavedModelBuilder(export_dir)
 builder.add_meta_graph_and_variables(sess, ["nn"])
 builder.save(as_text=False)
```

I would like the smallest save file with which I can run classification with. Specifically I am looking to exclude Adam variables that were created during training from the save file.

When I iterate on the values returned by `tf.all_variables()` prior to saving, I get variables I expect like:

```
tf.Variable 'mymodel/fully_connected/weights:0' shape=(128, 100) dtype=float32_ref
```

But also two Adam copies of the same:

```
tf.Variable 'mymodel/train/mymodel/fully_connected/weights/Adam:0' shape=(128, 100) dtype=float32_ref

tf.Variable 'mymodel/train/mymodel/fully_connected/weights/Adam_1:0' shape=(128, 100) dtype=float32_ref
```

This triples the size of my checkpoint file and I am constrained by the target system. The save file will only be used for classification, not training, so I don't need Adam optimizer variables.

Any suggestions on how I can most easily not have these written to the save file?

Any other suggestions for reducing save file size while still being able to run classification are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up getting things working using the following code.

I saved the graph, weights, biases, etc. like this:

```
  with tf.Session(graph=tf.Graph()) as sess:
    // Checkpoint of trained model that has Adam optimizer variables
    tf.saved_model.loader.load(sess, ["audio_nn"], FLAGS.checkpoint_dir)

    # Dump out checkpoint without Adam optimizer variables
    saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.model_variables())
    saver.save(sess, 'my-model')
```

Fortunately tf.model_variables() returned only the variables needed for the model and not the Adam optimizer variables.

And restored for classification like this:

```
 with tf.Session(graph=tf.Graph()) as sess:
    imported_meta = tf.train.import_meta_graph("my-model.meta")
    imported_meta.restore(sess, "my-model")

    features_tensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name( params.INPUT_TENSOR_NAME)
    prediction_tensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name( 'mymodel/prediction:0')

    ... prediction code ...
```

The checkpoint file is now about one third the size as before.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue, but my tf.model_variables() was empty. I was able to save only the necessary variables using your same idea except substituting tf.model_variables() with tf.trainable_variables(). This nicely excludes the ADAM variables. My model saving code looks as follows:

```
saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.trainable_variables())
saver.save(session, 'model.ckpt')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the variables in the saver:

`saver = tf.train.Saver(...variables...)
saver.save(sess, 'my-model', global_step=step)`

Reference: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Saver